# powershell get-content ignore newline

Tags: regex, powershell, get, newline

When you use set-content `Set-Content C:\test.txt "test","test1"` by default the two provided strings are separated by a newline, but there is also a newline at the end of the file.

How do you ignore this newline or newline with spaces when using Get-Content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove empty line like this:

```
Set-Content C:\test.txt "test",'',"test1"
Get-Content c:\test.txt | ? { $_ }
```

However, it will remove the string in the middle as well. 

*Edit:* Actually as I tried the example, I noticed that `Get-Content` ignores the last empty line added by `Set-Content`.

I think your problem is in `Set-Content`. If you use workaround with `WriteAllText`, it will work fine:

```
[io.file]::WriteAllText('c:\test.txt', ("test",'',"test1" -join "`n"))
```

You pass a string as second parameter. That's why I first joined the strings via `-join` and then passed it to the method.

*Note:* this is not recommended for large files, because of the string concatenation that is not efficient.

Comment: The [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) method works with collections, avoiding the need to `-join` the array into a single string: `[IO.File]::WriteAllLines('c:\test.txt', ("test",'',"Test1"))`

Answer (score 0):

it is default behavior that Set-Content adds new line because it lets you set-content with arrays of strings and get them one per line. Anyway Get-Content ignores last "new line" (if there are no spaces behind).
work around for Set-Content:

```
([byte[]][char[]] "test"), ([byte]13), ([byte]10) ,([byte[]][char[]] "test1") | 
   Set-Content c:\test.txt -Encoding Byte
```

or use much simplier `[io.file]::WriteAllText`

can you specify exact situation (or code)?

for example if you want to ignore last line when getting content it would look like:

```
$content = Get-Content c:\test.txt
$length = ($content | measure).Count
$content = $content | Select-Object -first ($length - 1)
```

but if you just do:

```
"test","test1" | Set-Content C:\test.txt 
$content = Get-Content C:\test.txt
```

`$content` variable contains two items: `"test","test1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content C:\test.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}
```